# PHP: Long page not displayed / Connection was reset

Tags: php, configuration, timeout

I have page listing few records from db.
After upgrading to PHP 5.3 site printing long records list is not displayed - Explorer says "**Connection was reset**"

I've changed SQL query in code to limit records and then page was shown correctly
So it seems to be some kind of timeout set.

I've tried find some settings in **PHP.ini , HTTPD.conf** - changed all sounds similar to timeout but nothing happened.

Any idea how to make it working ?

**EDIT**
Page resets after ~2 secs - so there is no extremely long time....

**EDIT-2**
I've tried set php vars: max_execution_time, max_input_time, memory_limit

---

WAMPServer 2 (PHP 5.3, Apache 2.2.11)

Answer (score 0):

At the top of your .php file, insert something like:

```
set_time_limit(120);
```

That sets the timeout for the script to 2 minutes. Increase it as you need.

I would recommend avoiding this problem by paginating your results, otherwise you're opening yourself up to a world of trouble. Slow pages are an open door for a denial of service attack by resource exhaustion.

Comment: Actually I have tried this before.
I'm not worry about security because this is Intranet page used internally by few ppl only